# How to save a single document field in cloud firestore into a local variable in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, document-database

I would like to save a single document field into a local variable, but I am not able to do that.
Here is my code:

```
void getPostsData() async{
    List<Widget> listItems = [];
    String _title;
    String _content;
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('Social_Posts').getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    documents.forEach((data){
      listItems.add(
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async{
              print(data["postTitle"]);
              print(data["postContent"]);
              setState(() {
               data["postTitle"] == _title;
               data["postContent"] == _content;
              });
              print(_title);
            },
       )
    );
      }
```

Whenever I try to print out "_title" or "_content", I get null. Why is that happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code never assigns a value to either `_title` or `_content`.  It's unclear what to do to fix this.  Please edit your question to describe your intent.  What is the goal with this code?

Comment: whats the output of `print(documents.length)` ?

Comment: I have attempted to save the field value to the 2 variables in the setState function. That is not working. I would like to save the value of data["postTitle"] to _title and data["postContent"] to content. @Doug Stevenson

Comment: the output of document.length is 15 @P4yam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change

```
       data["postTitle"] == _title;
       data["postContent"] == _content;
```

to:

```
       _title = data["postTitle"];
      _content= data["postContent"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between "data["postTitle"] = _title;" and " _title = data["postTitle"];" Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @AneeshYalgi == is comparison, if you wanna compare x and 2, you do if (x == 2) and the output of this would be a true or false